# how to use image in dark mode drawable even in normal mode?

Tags: android, darkmode

I'm making an android app with dark mode applied

I Manage background images in drawable-xx and drawable-night-xx.

But even in normal mode, I want to use background image in drawable-night-xx for specific layout.

How can I do it?
(I'm looking for a way to avoid renaming the image)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put the same drawable in both folders.

Comment: Thanks to reply.
I only want to use dark mode images in that case.

Android automatically recognizes the folder and opens it in normal mode, I want to know if there is a way to select a dark mode image arbitrarily.

Comment: not to my knowledge - and there shouldn't be - that would defeat the whole purpose. you would have to create different drawables with different names (as you've already mentioned, that you don't want to do) which would only be available as a 'normal' variant, though they'd be dark.

Comment: +1 Thank you so much. I want to ask one more question. Can't I set the Dark theme in Resource.getDrawable()? I don't know how to use this method.

Comment: the `night`-qualified resources are tied to the users' device system settings' dark theme - you can implement your own dark theme in your app by just defining a set of theme(s) for dark, but then you would be responsible for changing the theme.. and in that case, yes - you could apply a different theme to a specific drawable. 

another thing you could do is use color attributes in your drawable which you could override in your themes - then if you apply a theme to the drawable and set it programmatically the color(s) would be changed.

Comment: how can i use getDrawable({resource.id}, {theme}) method???
I don't know how to put theme in to the method?

Comment: assuming you would want to apply a theme which is different than the current activity/context - you would need to create a ContextThemeWrapper:
`val theme = ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.MyTheme)
val newImage = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(resources, R.drawable.ic_some_image, theme.theme)
imageView.setImageDrawable(newImage)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225401/discussion-between-jana-and-daisyyoun).

Comment: I checked late and couldn't join the chat:( Thanks for the answer, I tried the way you told me, but it didn't work, so I just decided to create a file... Thank you!